# Eclipse classes dont update on save

Tags: java, eclipse, class, debugging

When I save a java file in Eclipse and try to debug the code, it only runs the class files that were compiled from the most recent export of that project. Im not sure why this is happening nor do I know what I did to cause it.

Comment: Have you built the project, or have 'build automatically' enabled in the Project menu?

Comment: Build automatically was disabled. Thanks!